# Network bandwidth monitor with min/average/max rates

Tags: networking

Couldn't find anything like that.Have tried already tons of monitors.

Can anyone suggest one with required options?

Would be awesome if it

Comment: Does your edge routing gear support Netflow?

Comment: Any RRD based performance collector gives these, Hobbit, Nagios, Zenoss. Is "free" a requirement here? What about platform? Type of devices?

Comment: All monitoring solutions are showing an average over a period of time. The "Min" is actually the minimum for the average over a longer period of time and the "Max" is the maximum of the average for a longer period of time. If you consider instant bandwidth Min is 0 all time, and Max equals maximum bandwidth of the interface.

Comment: Anything for Ubuntu terminal only?

Comment: Well... what about bash_scripting + /sbin/ip or /sbin/ss + rrdtool?

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) for monitoring and graphing of the results.